# Restrict Place Order if Shipping Country is USA

Tags: checkout, shipping, magento-2.1.2, countries

I want to RESTRICT "Place Order" for Shipping Country USA if certain products are in Cart.

Can anyone please suggest me how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Check this article:

http://inchoo.net/magento/sorry-we-cant-ship-there/

Also there is some paid modules, that offer this functionality.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But I am looking for this functionality in magento 2.